# questions about drawing waveform lines (java)

Tags: java

Given these instructions, I'd be very grateful if someone could help undestand
the questions written as comments.

My purpose is to build an audio tool , in java, whose main feature is :
- displaying a signal waveform while an audio file is being played.

Thank you very much..Ulrike

```
// here the list lines , does it store points (line coordinates) ???


     List<Byte> audioBytes;
     List<Line2D.Double> lines;




    public void addAudioByte(byte b) {
                audioBytes.add(b);
            }




public void createWaveForm() {

       if (audioBytes.size() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        AudioFormat format = audioInputStream.getFormat();


        Dimension d = getSize();
        int w = d.width;
        int h = d.height - 15;



            // calculate number of frames per pixel 


int frames_per_pixel = audioBytes.size() / format.getFrameSize() / w;
        byte my_byte = 0;
        double y_last = 0;
        int numChannels = format.getChannels();
        for (double x = 0; x < w && audioData != null; x++) {
            // here what happens???
            int idx = (int) (frames_per_pixel * numChannels * x);

            if (format.getSampleSizeInBits() == 8) {
                my_byte = (byte) audioData[idx];
            } else {
                    // here what happens???


my_byte = (byte) (128 * audioData[idx] / 32768);
            }
                // does this code draw the line ???
                // Y samples values


double y_new = (double) (h * (128 - my_byte) / 256);
            lines.add(new Line2D.Double(x, y_last, x, y_new));
            y_last = y_new;
        }


        repaint();
    }
    // does this method draw the lines??? what does it do?  
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            // component dimensions
            Dimension d = getSize();
            g.setColor(getBackground());
            g.fillRect(0, 0, d.width, d.height);

            if (audioBytes.size() == 0) {
                return;
            }

            // I suppose this is where the lines are actually drawn 
        // The lines (so the waveform) are points and here they get connected based on the content
        // of the list lines (declared above) ..is my reasoning correct?        
            g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            for (int i = 1; i < lines.size(); i++) {
                Line2D.Double line = lines.get(i);
                g.drawLine((int) line.x1, (int) line.y1, (int) line.x2, (int) line.y2);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `createWaveforms()` method seems to be analyzing the audio file and creating a List called `lines` of lines (of type Line2D). These line objects each have a starting and end point, denoted by x1,y1 and x2,y2.

The `paint()` method has a loop to go through all those stored lines and draw a line on the canvas corresponding to the stored line segment. Assuming the rest of the code works, those lines will look like - well, probably a wave.

Answer (score 0):

First of all thank you for asking this because I'm curious as well about the numbers used and if they should change depending on the data for example I'm currently recording and playing back with a rate o 128k so there are a lot more bytes than 44100.

Any way I think I can answer this part of your question..

```
// here what happens???

    int idx = (int) (frames_per_pixel * numChannels * x);
```

I believe it is determining how many frames of audio data will be represented in each pixel of the waveform and setting idx to the first byte of each chunk of data skipping the bytes in between.

Comment: You sure she still wants to know after almost three years?